# The type or namespace name 'Controls' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C#(.NET Project) targetted to VS2008 and .net framework 2.0.When i Compile the project i am getting the above error.So,kindly give some suggestions on how to resolve this error.

Namespaces Used:

```
using System;

using System.Collections;
//using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows;
//using System.Windows.Controls;

using System.Windows.Controls.Control;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Regards,
Ranjan VijayKumar.

Comment: @user..is it a winforms application ?

Comment: As far as I can tell that namespace doesn't exist. What are you using it for?

Answer (score 2):

If you refer to MSDN you will notice `System.Windows.Controls` is not supported by Microsoft .Net Framework 2.0.

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls(v=vs.85).aspx).

[image]